# JSF : java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base : Only if context root is changed

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, message-bundle

I have read a lot of threads with the MissingResourceException problem. 
I'm using Primefaces 5.1.3
In my case I have the error :

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base [...], locale
```

In face-config.xml :

```
 <message-bundle>message.erreur.MsgErreurPrimefaces</message-bundle>
```

And in my sources :

[image]

The war is packed in an EAR. It works fine when I keep the default context root but if I change the context root, I get the message.

The file is present in the war's WEB-INF folder under :

> WEB-INF/classes/message/erreur/MsgErreurPrimefaces_fr_FR.properties

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this kind of error before and my problem has been corrected by editing as below. First of all, I would recommend you to add and test the MsgErreurPrimefaces.properties file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>message.erreur.MsgErreurPrimefaces</base-name>
            <var>myBundle</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
    <application>
        <message-bundle>message.erreur.MsgErreurPrimefaces</message-bundle>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>fr_FR</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr_FR</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>en_US</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```